# Merge Sort Output isn't Correct

Tags: c++, mergesort

So, I have had a few issues already but I think I have made significant progress on my own & have tried many things. However I can not get this to output the correct values I conceptually understand merge sort, but coding it is confusing me. So... If I input:

5
1
7
4
6
9

Instead of: 14569, I get (and I can't figure out why):
11414761467
 ** Also, as a question on the side, is there an easy way to loop in a set of numbers so that it doesn't require a new line in between in this situation?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int[], int, int, int);

void mergesort(int array[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if(low < high){
        mid = low + (high-low)/2;
        mergesort(array, low, mid);
        mergesort(array, mid+1, high);
        merge(array, low, mid, high);
    }
}

void merge(int array[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int h, i, j, b[high], k;
    h = low;
    i = low;
    j = mid + 1;
    while((h <= mid) && (j <= high)){
        if(array[h] <= array[j]){
            b[i] = array[h];
            h++;
        }
        else{
            b[i] = array[j];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if( h > mid){
        for(k = j; k <= high; k++){
            b[i] = array[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    else{
        for(k = h; k <= mid; k++){
            b[i] = array[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    for( k = low; k <= high; k++){
        array[k] = b[k];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < high; i++){
        cout << array[i];
    } 
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int data[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cin >> data[i] ;
    }
    mergesort(data, 0, size-1);
}
```

Also is there a way to cin >> data[i] without having to press enter after every one, but without using vectors? Thanks so much again.

Comment: To make your code more readable: remove extra blank lines and make sure you indent properly (no tabs, 4 spaces per indent).

Comment: You should declare b[high+1] in merge().

Comment: Technically that isn't a C++ program, because C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). If you want to use a variable-sized "array" you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: You can `cin >> data[i]` by separating each integer by a space and pressing enter once at the end. Since your code also takes the size immediately before you enter the number you can also specify the size in the same line. i.e. `4 1 2 3 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are printing in each recursion of merge(), thats why you are getting it like that, as the print happens as and when a merge happens and does not just print the end result.

```
for(int i = 0; i < high; i++){
    cout << array[i];
}
```

To avoid this, print the merged array in main.

---

What i mean is change your program to:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int[], int, int, int);

void mergesort(int array[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if(low < high){
        mid = (high+low)/2;
        mergesort(array, low, mid);
        mergesort(array, mid+1, high);
        merge(array, low, mid, high);
    }
}

void merge(int array[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int h, i, j, b[high], k;
    h = low;
    i = low;
    j = mid + 1;
    while((h <= mid) && (j <= high)){
        if(array[h] <= array[j]){
            b[i] = array[h];
            h++;
        }
        else{
            b[i] = array[j];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if( h > mid){
        for(k = j; k <= high; k++){
            b[i] = array[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    else{
        for(k = h; k <= mid; k++){
            b[i] = array[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    for( k = low; k <= high; k++){
        array[k] = b[k];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int data[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cin >> data[i] ;
    }
    mergesort(data, 0, size-1);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << data[i];
    } 
}
```

Comment: Wow... Thank you so much. I can't believe I didn't think of that. I guess I need a ton more practice.